# Python/Flask + WTForm - File upload not working, <input> field not picking up

Tags: python, flask

I am having an issue uploading file from my local file system using Flask + WTF Forms. It seems like browser is blocking me load the file into the `<input/>` field for some reason. Event is not picking up. I even get this message.

```
<input> picker was blocked due to lack of user activation.
```

What is funny about it is that I remember this working couple of weeks ago when I was testing it.

Here is what my HTML + JS looks like:

```
...

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="file-input">
            <input type="file" class="nft1-file-collect">
            <label for="signature">{{signature}}</label>
            {{ form.signature(id_='signature', onchange='showSignaturePreview(event)') }}
            <span class="nft1-file-location">Choose a File</span>
            <button type="button" class="nft1-file-browse">Browse</button>
            <span class="file-formate">PNG Transparent, Max 150MB</span>

            <img id="signature_preview" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/docs/signature-generic.png') }}" style="display: block;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 250px;" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

...
function showSignaturePreview(event){
    if (event.target.files.length > 0){
        var src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
        var preview = document.getElementById("signature_preview")
        preview.src = src;
        preview.style.display = "block"
    }
}
```

Here is what `form.py` looks like:

```
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileRequired
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import Form, StringField, validators 
from wtforms.fields import DateField, IntegerField, HiddenField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, InputRequired

class FileUploadForm(FlaskForm):
    name           = StringField('name', render_kw={'class':'input-text'}, validators=[validators.data_required()])
    date_of_birth  = DateField('dob', render_kw={'class':'input-text'}, validators=[validators.data_required()])
    signature      = FileField('signature', render_kw={'class':'nft1-file-collect'}, validators=[validators.optional()])
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: did you check if there are error messages in JavaScript console (in `DevTool`). You could also use `console.log()` display infromation which part of code was executed and what you have in variables. If you load some JavaScript library then you should check tab `Network` in `DevTool` to see if it has problem to load this library.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I've needed to update Flask to newest version, because I was using Chrome 100+. I am not sure why, but after the update everything works fine.